# Conditional tags with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml

I have this haml:

```
.kudobox
  %div.kudos= number_to_human_size_not_bytes kudos
  %div= (kudos == 1 || kudos == -1) ? "kudo" : "kudos"
```

Now I want the `.kudobox` have a `positive`, `negative` or `zero` class, depending on the number of kudos:

```
-# < 0 kudos
<div class="kudobox negative">

-# == 0 kudos
<div class="kudobox zero">

-# > 0 kudos
<div class="kudobox positive">
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

---

I know I can

```
%div{ :class => ( kudos < 0 ? "kudobox negative" : ( kudos == 0 ? "kudobox zero" : ( kudos > 0 ? "kudobox positive" : "kudobox impossible" ) ) ) }
```

But isn't there a shorter way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't looked too closely at your code (it's kind of confusing to read) to tell you if there's a *shorter* way, but I can say that you'd be much better off writing a helper method than having all of that logic in the view.  A helper method with a plain old **if** or **case** statement would get the job done more cleanly, and then length wouldn't really be a factor.  That way, you could replace the long conditional statement in your view with something easy on the eyes, like

```
%div{ :class => kudobox(kudos) }
```

Comment: Yes, do this. It's a perfect case for a helper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just short code without a helper, here you are:

```
.kudobox(class="#{kudos<0?'negative':kudos==0?'zero':'positive'}")
```